# How to get two different array checkbox value in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

For example i have 5 checkbox, 3 checkbox with name=a[] and 2 checkbox with name=b[], if i checked array a[] 3checkbox iam getting the same value for b[] checkbox even b[] checkbox not checked. please suggest...

For ur reference:

```
var selectedAItems = new Array();
$("input[@name='a[]']:checked").each(function() {
    selectedAItems.push($(this).val());
});

var selectedBItems = new Array();
$("input[@name='b[]']:checked").each(function() {
    selectedBItems.push($(this).val());
});
alert(selectedAItems);
alert(selectedBItems );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax with `@` in the selector is deprecated since version 1.1.4 of jQuery and has been removed since version 1.3.

Just remove the `@` from your selectors and it should work as expected

`$("input[@name='a[]']:checked")` ↯

`$("input[name='a[]']:checked")` ✔